# Extract version number

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I am trying to just get the version number from an HML link.

Take this for example

```
firefox-10.0.2.bundle
```

I have got it to take everything after the `-` with

```
string versionNum = name.Split('-').Last();
versionNum = Regex.Replace(versionNum, "[^0-9.]", "");
```

which gives you an output of

> 10.0.2

However, if the link is like this

```
firefox-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2
```

the output will look like

> 10.0.2...2

How can I make it so that it just chops everything off after the third `.`? Or can I make it so that when first letter is detected it cuts that and everything that follows?

Comment: You could do everything in one regex, extracting/capturing the number you want using capture groups `(`...`)`. Online regex services (such as https://www.debuggex.com/ , https://regex101.com/, http://regexstorm.net/tester) can help you build and test your regex against any test strings (which is much better and easier than trial-and-error in C# code)

Comment: Use the Match method, not the Replace method.

Comment: Possibility a) use a substring() with an offset. Possibility b) Split the resulting string again for '.' an only take what you need.

Comment: @sublimeaces I highly recommend you check out my answer, to gain a better understanding of more advanced and robust regexes, if not to accept it as a better answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this with a single regex match.
Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+.\d+.\d+");
        Match match = regex.Match("firefox-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after you split "firefox-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2" to "10.0.2.source.tar.bz2"

```
string a = "10.0.2.source.tar.bz2";
string[] list = a.Split(new char [] { '.' });
string output = ""
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if item is integer then // try to write this part
        output += item + ".";


}
after that remove the last character from output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Although late, I feel that this answer would be much more apt:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[\d\.]+(?![a-zA-Z\-])");
Match m = r.Match(name);

Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

**Improvements -**

Though `@Samuel`'s answer works, what happens if the build is `10.2.2.3`? His regex would give `10.2.2` - a partial answer, and therefore, wrong.

With the regex I have posted, the match would be complete.

## Explanation -

`[\d\.]+` matches all the combination of numbers and dots such as `10.2.2.34.56.78` and even just `10` if the build is `10.bundle`

`(?![a-zA-Z\-])` is a negative look-ahead which ensures that the match is not followed by any letter or dash.

Being robust is absolutely vital to any code, so my posted answer should work pretty well under any circumstances (because the link could be anything).

Comment: NB: What happens for inputs "1..1" or "1.1.-"?

Comment: @JohnLBevan `1.1.-` would still work with this regex.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Also, what do you mean by `1..1`?

Comment: @CoffehouseCoder, the strings I gave are examples of strings which are not version numbers, but would still be matched by your version of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version which can handle 1-4 numbers (not just digits) in the input string, and returns a version number:

```
public static Version ExtractVersionNumber(string input)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+\.){0,3}\d+");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return new Version(match.Value);
    }
    return null;
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2.5.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2.5.6.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2.5source.tar.bz2"));
    Console.WriteLine(ExtractVersionNumber("firefox-10.0.2.5.6source.tar.bz2"));
}
```

#### Explanation

There are essentially 2 parts:

1. `(\d+\.){0,3}` -match a number (uninterrupted sequence of 1 or more digits) immediately followed by a dot.  Match this 0 to 3 times.
2. `\d+` - match a number (sequence of 1 or more digits).

These work as follows:

- When there's only 1 number (or even if there's only 1 number followed by a dot), the first part will match nothing, the second part will match the number
- when there are 2 numbers separated by a dot, the first part matches the first number and the dot, the second part matches the second number.
- for 3 numbers separated by dots, the first part gets the first 2 numbers & dots, the last the third number
- for 4 or more numbers separated by dots, the first part gets the first 3 numbers and dots, the second gets the fourth number.  Any subsequent numbers and dots are ignored.

ps. If you wanted to ensure that you only got the number after the hyphen (e.g. to avoid getting `4.0.1` given the string `firefox4.0.1-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2"`) you could add a negative look behind to say "the character immediately before the version number must be a hyphen": `(?<=-)(\d+\.){0,3}\d+`.